# Desktop Windows App to include capabilities

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime

I am trying to test the newer [Geolocation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Geolocation) (in place of the older ILocation COM API), which is a WinRT API.

I 've followed instructions from [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#uY24fx48tOb2WuIz.97) to allow a normal C++ desktop Win32 app to call Windows 10 RT functions. It works normally in my tests.

However, for location, I must include a capability in a XML file as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location).

How am I supposed to create this XML file? I tried creating a file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
   <Capabilities>
    <!-- DeviceCapability elements must follow Capability elements (if present) -->
    <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
  </Capabilities>
  <Identity Name="" 
            Version="" 
            Publisher="" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName></DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName></PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo></Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion></OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested></OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="" StartPage="">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="" Description=""
           Logo="" SmallLogo=""  
           ForegroundText="" BackgroundColor="">
         <SplashScreen Image="" />
      </VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

I am not sure what to do from now on. Is there a compiler setting that would tell the compiler/linker to include this appxmanifest file?

Thanks

Comment: Which compiler/toolchain are you using? Most of the instructions you linked to are for Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you see https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/ ? Might be useful.

Comment: Desktop apps automatically possess most capabilities. There are a few that require explicit declaration, like `runFullTrust`, but most of them are possessed automatically because desktop apps run at medium integrity.